# Gesture recognition library in C# or R

Tags: c#, .net, r, gesture

I'm working on .NET project which has objects that represent hand and arm 3D motion. These objects contains time, position and velocity vectors. I need an .NET libary that can detect simple gestures such as circles and swipes. The input for the library's API should be vector of time/position/velocity and output should be an indicator that a specific gesture was performed in a specific timerange. I prefer an .NET library but R library is fine too. I tried to search for simple library I could use for gesture recognition but all I found was Real Time applications. Can somebody recommend me a library with an API as above?

Comment: This question is specifically [off-topic on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *recommend or find a book, tool, software library*. You might get responses at [SoftwareRecs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Good luck, though ... there are not many places to ask that kind of question with as many devs available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many such packages in nuget, you can install in your project and use as regular references. Here are some for gesture recognition.

```
https://www.nuget.org/packages/i2e.gesture-recognition/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Naxam.MapboxGestures.Droid/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MotionGestures/
```